# how should I design Objects around this business requirement?

Tags: java, design, object-oriented, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

This is the business requirement:

"
A Holiday Package (e.g. New York NY Holiday Package) can be offered in different ways based on the Origin city:

- From New Delhi to NY
- **From Bombay to NY**
- NY itself ( Land package )

(Bold implies default selection)

**a.** and **b.** User can fly from either New Delhi or Bombay to NY. 
**c.** NY is a Land package, where a user can reach NY by himself and is a standalone holidayPackage.
"

Let's say I have a class that represents **HolidayPackage**, **Destination** (aka City).

```
public class HolidayPackage{
    Destination holidayCity;
    ArrayList<BaseHolidayPackageVariant> variants;
    BaseHolidayPackageVariant defaultVariant;
}

public abstract class BaseHolidayPackageVariant {
    private Integer variantId;
    private HolidayPackage holidayPackage;
    private String holidayPackageType;
}

public class LandHolidayPackageVariant extends BaseHolidayPackageVariant{
}

public class FlightHolidayPackageVariant extends BaseHolidayPackageVariant{
    private Destination originCity;
}
```

What data structure/objects should I design to support:

- options
- a default within those options

Sidenote: A HolidayPackage can also be offered in different ways based on Hotel selections. I'd like to follow a design which I can leverage to support that use case in the future.

This is the [backend design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14665/1008) I have in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the proposed database schema, you could have a class called **HolidayPackage** with attributes of type **Hotel**, **City**, and **PackageVersion**.

**PackageVersion** would be a superclass of **LandPackageVersion** and **FlightPackageVersion**.  It is declared as the generic **PackageVersion** so that polymorphism or dependency injection can be used to populate it with the appropriate subclass.

```
public Class HolidayPackage{

    Hotel hotel;
    City city;
    PackageVersion package;  //could be an instance of LandPackageVersion or FlightPackageVersion
    .
    .
    .
```

### Edit

OK, now that you have edited your question to show your class structure, I can see you already have it organized how I was recommending above.  So this should work fine as long as you have methods that tell you information about each **BaseHolidayPackageVariant** in the **variants** ArrayList, such as whether or not there is a flight associated with it.

Oversimplified example:

```
public abstract class BaseHolidayPackageVariant {

    public boolean hasFlight(){}
}

public class LandHolidayPackageVariant extends BaseHolidayPackageVariant{

    public boolean hasFlight(){
        return false;
    }
}

public class FlightHolidayPackageVariant extends BaseHolidayPackageVariant{

    public boolean hasFlight(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, at runtime, you don't really need to use instanceOf() because you'll know everything you need to know about the Objects using these descriptive methods.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit. Apart from handling options and default, I'm faced with a concern: At runtime, how can I know if a given Object in `variants[]` is of Type LandPackageVariant or FlightPackageVariant ?

Comment: @brainydexter You can use Java's [instanceOf()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm) to know an Object's type at runtime.  However, you should try to design it so it doesn't matter what type of object it is.  This can be achieved by effectively [overriding methods](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31).

Comment: I agree with that article (I had actually read the very same Scott Meyer's article against instanceOf()). For the very same reason, I am trying to come up with a better design to the problem I asked in my question.

Comment: @brainydexter See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current implementation it sounds like the holiday package should contain a travel mechanism (air, land, from, to), a place to stay, and also what you are currently calling the base package. Your options should be a list of holiday packages that contain different combinations of the travel, hotel, and base package properties.

If the presented packages are supposed to have a default you can simply add a integer value that is the sort/rank index and then decide that the default is the one with the lowest or highest number.